# FBSDKShareDialog not working on IOS11

Tags: objective-c, ios11, fbsdk

I am using `FBSDKShareDialog` to share an image on facebook, but on IOS11 it is not working. The Facebook share dialog is not opening.

How can I share the post and have it work on IOS11 and previous versions as well.

My previous working code:

```
FBSDKSharePhoto *photo = [[FBSDKSharePhoto alloc] init];
photo.image = img;
photo.userGenerated = YES;
FBSDKSharePhotoContent *content = [[FBSDKSharePhotoContent alloc] init];
content.photos = @[photo];
[FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self withContent:content delegate:self];
```

Comment: are you login with facebook in your device ?

Comment: yes @NisarAhmad

Answer (score 3):

Update to the latest Facebook Frameworks.

```
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.27.0'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.27.0'
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '~> 4.27.0'
```

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks